# Standard Scaler Producing Unexpected Result for Just One Column

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, preprocessor, training-data

I'm doing some preprocessing on my training data before fitting it to a model. Upon checking the results, there is one column that is returning 0 rather than 1 for the standard deviation. (all columns return a mean of 0 as expected). My code is below:

```
y = ml_df['target']
x = ml_df[['Feature1', 'Feature2', 'Feature3', 'Feature4', 'Feature5', 'Feature6', 
           'Feature7', 'Feature8', 'Feature9', 'Feature10', 'Feature11', 'Feature12']]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.55, random_state=3)

pt_hp = PowerTransformer()
x_train_gaussian = pt_hp.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_gaussian =  pt_hp.transform(x_test)

ss_hp = StandardScaler()
std_x_train = ss_hp.fit_transform(x_train_gaussian)
std_x_test = ss_hp.transform(x_test_gaussian)
```

After running the above, this line produces the following output:

```
print(std_x_train.std(axis = 0))
```

Output: [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]

This particular feature is not materially different than the others; is contains only positive values (no zeros that would impact PowerTransformer) and not anywhere close to near-zero variance. I realize the PowerTransformer also scales the data so the final 2 lines are currently unneccessary, but both `x_train_gaussian` and `std_x_train` return this output so I don't think that's the issue here.

Does anyone have any idea why this one particular column is returning such a different standard deviation than the rest? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Because this question is less concerned with programming and more with classification methodology and/or training parameters it is better suited for the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: It was clearly suitable for here as well but YC

Comment: posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/107907/55122

Answer (score 0):

Issue was apparently caused by long-standing SKlearn bug - https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14959